# If $x$ is real and $p=\frac{3(x^2+1)}{2x-1}$, prove that $p^2-3(p+3)\ge0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $x$ is real and $p=\frac{3(x^2+1)}{2x-1}$, prove that $p^2-3(p+3)\ge0$

So far, I have tried to substitute the value of $p$ into $p^2-3(p+3)$ and tried to see if I could find anything that would lead me to the conclusion that the expression is greater than or equal to zero.

What I have ended up with is $\frac{9\{(x^2+1)^2-(2x-1)(x^2+1)-(2x-1)^2\}}{(2x-1)^2}$

I do not see how this could lead me to proving what the questions asks however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that
$$(2x-1)p=3(x^2+1)\Rightarrow 3x^2-2px+3+p=0.$$
Now consider the discriminant.

Comment: Arrghh... you beat me by like 10 seconds.

Comment: Very efficient! +1

Comment: I used your hint to find the discriminant of the equation. And then I remembered that if there are real roots, it means that the discriminant has to be greater than or equal to zero. It was even in the question, and I was trying to puzzle out what information was required to prove what the question asks. Many thanks @mathlove for setting me on the right path!