# Property of a fractional expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I saw the following question

[If $x$ is real and $p=\frac{3(x^2+1)}{2x-1}$, prove that $p^2-3(p+3)\ge0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525985/if-x-is-real-and-p-frac3x212x-1-prove-that-p2-3p3-ge0)

I've really tried to understand the answer but I still don't get it... The discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ seems always < 0. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: This isn't a title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x is real, so the discriminant has to be at least 0. This means that $(2p)^2-4*3*(p+3)\ge 0$. Dividing this by 4 gives $p^2-3(p+3)\ge 0$, as desired.

Edit: Since the link in the original post was deleted here it is:

[If $x$ is real and $p=\frac{3(x^2+1)}{2x-1}$, prove that $p^2-3(p+3)\ge0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525985/if-x-is-real-and-p-frac3x212x-1-prove-that-p2-3p3-ge0?noredirect=1&lq=1)